# Is there a way to fix a div without it floating right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jquery to fix a div to the top of the screen when one scrolls.

However when it reaches the top, it floats to the right of the window instead of staying in place.

```
    .title{
        font-size:200%;
        background-color:#282C2F;
        color: #EFEFEF;
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        border-radius:2px;
        opacity:.8;
    }

<div class="title">
        Timeline: Penguins in the city
    </div>
```

javascript

```
var titlePosition = $('.title').offset() //find timeline title position
var titleWidth = $('.title').width() //find time line title width

$(window).scroll(function() {

var scrollBar = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (scrollBar > titlePosition.top) { //a play on offset().top which finds top postion of an element
        $('.title').css("top","0px");
        $('.title').css("position","fixed");
        $('.title').css("width",titleWidth); //this is important...it makes the width of our newly fixed div stay the same.
        } else {
            $('.title').css("position","relative");
        };
}); //end of scroll function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
$('.title').css("right", "100px");  //or however much works in px or %
```

You don't have any left or right position on .title, so it seems like it stays in place at first, but then another element(s) pushes it to the right

Comment: Thanks but how do I determine "however much works in px or %"? I need it to be responsive.

It is in a bigger div. If I give it a specific px I don't want it to fall out of place again if the screen is smaller.

Comment: @user2559519 It takes a lot of work to make a great responsive website. The use of media queries helps for things like this. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ You just need to test it on different screen sizes. Most browsers will let you shrink the screen and give you a good idea of how it looks on all sizes. Then just adjust accordingly for those elements that need to be fine-tuned(adjusted)

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery for this?  Just use CSS to fix the position:

```
.title{
    font-size:200%;
    background-color:#282C2F;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-radius:2px;
    opacity:.8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/d3Z84/